# how initialize third party library (konvajs) in react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, konvajs, konva

I try to initialize third party library In React hooks I'm using useEffect but I get All the time **null**
I tried using custom hooks but I get the same result (null)

any idea?

this my code https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rg9uov

thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `useEffect` should declare dependency array for `ref`, also not sure why `const stage = useRef(null);` is used? `stage` could be just a component state.

```
 const [stage, setStage] = React.useState();
 const ref = useRef();

 useEffect(() => {
    if(ref.current){
      setStage(new Konva.Stage({
      container: ref.current, // id of container <div>
      width: 500,
      height: 300
    }))
    }

  },[ref]);
```

Comment: thank you, I have a question save stage in the state this is not bad for performance?

Comment: not really, if you want to get hold of Konva.Stage instance, you need to store it in your state

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing `null` because the `console.log` is running before `useEffect`, if you put a `console.log` at the end of `useEffect` you'll see that Konva is initialized properly.